# calculating distances of equally distributed lines in 3d space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have 5 lines (d1 -> d5) equally distributed from each other in 3d perspective, and I have the values of angle (a), (d1) and (b5). I need to calculate (b2, b3, b4, d2, d3, d4, d5).

[image]

I can calculate d5 with:

```
d5 = d1 - ( b5 * Math.tan(a))
```

but I have no idea how to calculate b2, b3 and b4. (d1 is divided into 4 identical segments.)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, razzak!  I've taken the liberty of fixing some of your spelling.

Comment: @Paul VanKoughnett: thanks